# Hot deploy war maven project in embedded tomcat

Tags: maven, hotdeploy, maven-tomcat-plugin

I  have maven war project.

I know inplace. it deploys to a given server. But i want to deploy on embedded tomcat and dont want to restart everytime. just say

for first time run deploy

Then change some java class and say redeploy. All in embedded tomcat.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Could the [Tomcat Maven Plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2/run-mojo-features.html) help with this?

You can use it by using the command `tomcat:run`

[This page](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2/index.html) describes how to set up your POM/settings to make calling the plugin easier (using a prefix vs having to use full groupId/artifactId of plugin on the command line).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look at the executable war/jar feature see http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2/executable-war-jar.html 
So that will produce a simple jar which contains tomcat classes. You will be able to simply run: java -jar pathtofile.jar.